# How to get "content_type" using Get File Properties REST API for Azure Files Storage using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to get the "content_type" property for files in Azure fileshare. I can get "last_modified" and "size" but not "content_type"

```
from azure.storage.file import *
from azure.storage.fileshare import *

def azure_connect_conn_string(source_file_connection_string, source_share_name):
    try:
        share_service = ShareServiceClient.from_connection_string(source_file_connection_string)#ShareServiceClient interact with the account level
        share_client = share_service.get_share_client(source_share_name) #desired share name is accessed
        file_service = FileService(connection_string=source_file_connection_string)
        print("Connection String -- Connected.")
        return share_client, file_service #returns the share client

    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error: " + str(ex))

def fileshare_content_list(connection_instance, directory_name, file_service, share_name):
    d_client = connection_instance.get_directory_client(directory_name)
    my_files = d_client.list_directories_and_files()
    directory_list = []

    for file in my_files:
        if file.get('is_directory'):
            #cannot get size of directory, only of files
            file_name = file.get('name')
            file_lastmod = file.get('last_modified')
            file_type = 'directory'
            file_size = 'unknown'

        else:
            file_name = file.get('name')
            file_props = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name, directory_name, file_name)
            file_lastmod = file_props.properties.last_modified
            file_size = file.get('size')
            print(file_name)
            print(file_lastmod)
            print(file_size)
            print(file_props.properties.content_type)

def main():
    try:
        azure_connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ecpcdmsdatamartexternal;AccountKey=neNa1jtdyVljMN/j403/rHwdYBpPUtKTreeYM4UsKiosiOfKdePgyZdJl8SK9UdAlsXwVvOkNdNWZjnOCyn/lw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        share_name = "ecdmpext"
        directory_name = "data"
        connection_instance, file_service = azure_connect_conn_string(azure_connection_string, share_name)

        ## List files
        fileshare_content_list(connection_instance, directory_name, file_service, share_name)
        print('Done')
    
    except Exception as ex:
        print('main | Error: ', ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get error `'FileProperties' object has no attribute 'content_type'`

When I try using `file.get("content_type")`  I just get "None".
I use `file.get()` for "size" and "name", for "last_modified" I have to use `file_service.get_file_properties.properties.last_modified` but neither method works for "content_type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there :). The `content_type` property is actually a sub property of [`content_settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.models.contentsettings?view=azure-python) property in [`File's property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.models.fileproperties?view=azure-python) returned by [`get_file_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.fileservice?view=azure-python#azure-storage-file-fileservice-fileservice-get-file-properties).

So your code would be something like:

```
file_content_type = file_props.properties.content_settings.content_type
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just realized it's not giving me the info I wanted. I thought it would give me the data type, do you know what the property for data type is? e.g "txt file, csv file, etc.". Or should I just use the "name" property and manually get the file extension like "data.txt -> txt"

Comment: I am guessing that you're getting `application/octet-stream` content type back. If that's the case that means you have not set the content type when uploading blob. Content type (and other content settings) is something that you have to set yourself (Azure Storage will not do that for you). You can do it at the time of uploading the file and also via set_properties operation. HTH.

Comment: yes exactly. So without it being set in advance I would have to manually determine the file type?

Comment: Yeah...that's correct.